# How to make Swagger map not used entity in Nest.js?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have my Nest.js project and I use Prisma as ORM. Therefore, there is actually no need for me to use entities to communicate with database, but I still want to document those entities using Swagger.

For example file `user.entity.ts`:

```
import { Users } from '@prisma/client';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class UserEntity implements Users {
  @ApiProperty()
  id: string;
  @ApiProperty()
  firstName: string;
  @ApiProperty()
  lastName: string;
  @ApiProperty()
  ...
```

Even though I export this class, I don't use it, because Prisma allows that. And the issue is that while it's not used somewhere (`@Body` decorator, for instance), Swagger can't map this entity and therefore I don't see it in my documentation.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is why it happens. I have found the [thread](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/954) about the same issue.

Generally speaking, without getting into details, if your model/entity is not used somewhere, even though you mapped it with `@ApiProperty()`, it won't be shown within documentation.

Therefore, I have used solution using `@ApiExtraModels()` decorator and passed all DTOs.

Hope it was hopeful.